# Группировка и кумулятивное суммирование DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть DataFrame 'result_data':

```
ind Name    Date        Value
0   Black   01.01.2018  15
1   Wick    08.01.2018  74
2   Jeff    09.01.2018  31
3   Wick    16.01.2018  26
4   Jeff    18.01.2018  74
5   Anit    20.01.2018  56
6   Anit    21.01.2018  78
7   Wick    30.01.2018  10
```

Необходимо для каждой строки высчитать сумму value по всему df, где name=name этой строки, а date<=date этой строки. Т.е. получить что-то подобное:

```
ind Name    Date        Value  Result
0   Black   01.01.2018  15     15
1   Wick    08.01.2018  74     74
2   Jeff    09.01.2018  31     31
3   Wick    16.01.2018  26     100
4   Jeff    18.01.2018  74     105
5   Anit    20.01.2018  56     56
6   Anit    21.01.2018  78     134
7   Wick    30.01.2018  10     110
```

Тривиальная задачка, но никак не получается её решить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
In [156]: df['Result'] = df.sort_values('Date').groupby('Name')['Value'].cumsum()

In [157]: df
Out[157]:
   ind   Name        Date  Value  Result
0    0  Black  01.01.2018     15      15
1    1   Wick  08.01.2018     74      74
2    2   Jeff  09.01.2018     31      31
3    3   Wick  16.01.2018     26     100
4    4   Jeff  18.01.2018     74     105
5    5   Anit  20.01.2018     56      56
6    6   Anit  21.01.2018     78     134
7    7   Wick  30.01.2018     10     110
```